# Rcpp cannot find gsl library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, gsl

im out of ideas

Im trying to create a library for R, but i cant get it to load.

The error im getting is

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/stenver/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-    library/2.15/RcppWilcoxonTest/libs/RcppWilcoxonTest.so':
  /home/stenver/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppWilcoxonTest/libs/RcppWilcoxonTest.so:     undefined symbol: gsl_cdf_gaussian_Q
Error: loading failed
```

My Makevars file looks like this:

```
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()" `
```

I have tried changing all kinds of stuff in there.

My NAMESPACE file looks like this:

```
useDynLib(RcppWilcoxonTest)
useDynLib(gsl)
useDynLib(WilcoxonTest)

import(Rcpp)

export(RcppWilcoxonTest)
```

The failure happens in the dynamic shared library i am trying to use. I have copied the dynamic library files to the src folder, so R would compile them itself, but it is of no use. Ideally, i would like to keep the library and Rcpp interface implementation in a separate folders.

At some point, i also tried to use RcppGSL, but it didnt help, as R couldnt find the package after install.

The entire repository can be seen here:

https://bitbucket.org/stenver/wilxoni-astaku-test/src/8c9b5da2cd9a97fd6c1a569e468c50ca95e2e06f?at=default

in the RcppWilcoxonTest folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like the following in your `src/Makevars` file; that is (borrowing from how `RcppGSL` does things):

```
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` `gsl-config --libs`
```

so R knows that it needs to link against GSL when compiling your package. See [R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) for more details.

You can probably learn a lot by checking how `RcppGSL` is configured to look for GSL, and use a similar approach in your package.

Comment: I get an: Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object 'gsl.so' not found. I have gsl-dev installed. I mean - i am making libraries with GSL. I copied the content exactly as you said and also put "PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include
" in there

Comment: Perhaps http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-installing-gsl-wrapper-td3020005.html will be informative.

Comment: The gsl-config --libs was really a useful trick. I ended up not using RcppGSL aswell, since i dont want to mix R and C++ code, except as little as possible - only a method call. Thanks for your help and quick response. I have no idea what wasnt working, since by now i have deleted NAMESPACE and makevar files and it still installs. I guess your answer is closer to my final solution so gratz. Im rally baffled in why it started working.. i think it will come back biting me, since i dont know the exact reason

Answer (score 4):

Kevin's answer will probably help you, but there is in fact one CRAN package explicitly depending on RcppGSL, and in it I do

```
edd@max:~/git/rcppziggurat/src$ cat Makevars
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` \
           `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
edd@max:~/git/rcppziggurat/src$
```

where I wrapped one line for the display here.

In essence, the RcppGSL invokes the same `gsl-config` that Kevin alluded to.

Comment: I tried both Kevin and yours. In your case it simply says: In file included from RcppWilcoxonTest.cpp:1:0:
./WilcoxonTest.h:10:21: fatal error: RcppGSL.h: No such file or director. I made the Makevars exactly as you said, tried fumbling around with them aswell. I also tried putting Import(RcppGSL) to NAMESPACE file. And i also tried putting RcppGSL as dependency in the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: I need to come to terms with what the -I and -L flags do, and learn on something simpler if you can't master this.  I walk through this slowly and in detail in an example in Chapter 2 of the Rcpp book.

Comment: Alright, thanks, i will take a look at them, though i believed that i know their meaning. Unfortunately its one of my requirements to integrate it with R. Not the simplest task to take when you are a beginner at best at cpp compiling, but i will figure something out. Im also considering ordering the book

Comment: I actually just got it working. I removed the stuff from NAMESPACE and even everything from Makevars file and it just.. works.. i even restarted everything to make sure that i didnt accidentally set some random variable. I ended up using the default gsl, since i want to mix cpp and R as little as possible - only a method call. C++ will do the heavy lifting in its own shared library. Thanks for the quick responses and help